# notepad++ cant connect using SFTP - Error during authentication: Invalid private key file

Tags: notepad++, sftp, private-key

Hi I created private key using puttygen,
I have successfully connected using putty, and using Filezilla.

But I cant seem to get it work with Notepad++

Im getting...

Host Key accepted, then...

Error during authentication: Invalid private key file.

I have inserted by IP,

selected 22 as port,

Ive selected SFTP

Ive put in my username with password blank

Under Authorization I have selected "Try Private Key File Authorization" with the private key file that Ive been using for the others as the one its pointing to in the field below

But despite all this Im still getting the error, might there be something stupid that I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notepad++'s SFTP client plug-in does not support keys in PPK (PuTTY) format.
Try saving your key in OpenSSH (RSA) format and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

To check it, try **SynWrite** with same NppFTP, updated to SynFTP (it's installed there, see FTP tab on left pane). Enter same file and test it.

Comment: Thanks, but it turns out I had to convert the key to open SSH, not sure I understand why but now I use two keys, one for that notepad, and the other for everything else. I didnt answer and as it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Log-in to your terminal. Make sure you are in /home/your_user_name/

First client private/public key

$ `ssh-keygen -t rsa`

1. Press Enter to choose default directory
2. You may choose a pass phrase here depending upon situation.

Now add your public rsa key details to authorized keys, use the following command

$ `cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

$  `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

After this delete the id_rsa.pub file if you wish.

Now the private key file id_rsa is the one you need to '`import`'.

You need the tool called the `puttygen` to import this file and then
click on the `Menu Bar` -> `Conversions` -> `Export OpenSSH Key` and save the exported file.

Save it as `npp.ppk` (maybe) and then use this in the Notepad++ Private key file path.